Issue with javafx text position
I want to draw texts in a javafx canvas, with alignment at the top. For my test, I tried to align my texts at the top of my window. My code works well for strings "a" or "ad", but there is a problem when the string contains characters with descendants (like "p" or "j"). In this case, the text is displayed lower than it should.
From what I understand, I use the height of my text to determine the y where to display it, but in the case where there is a descendant, the "y" that I pass there corresponds to the baseline, and not the bottom of the text
I configured the boundType to VISUAL, because I want my texts to be as close as possible to the top of my window.
Here is the code for my test :
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ImageView gridImageView = new ImageView();
        gridImageView.setFitHeight(50);
        gridImageView.setFitWidth(150);
        gridImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(Double.valueOf(gridImageView.getFitWidth()).intValue(),
                Double.valueOf(gridImageView.getFitHeight()).intValue());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(gridImageView.getFitWidth(), gridImageView.getFitHeight());
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 30));

        Text textA = new Text("a");
        textA.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        textA.setFont(gc.getFont());
        gc.strokeRect(20, 0, textA.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(), textA.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
        gc.fillText(textA.getText(), 20, textA.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());

        Text textAD = new Text("ad");
        textAD.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        textAD.setFont(gc.getFont());
        gc.strokeRect(50, 0, textAD.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(), textAD.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
        gc.fillText(textAD.getText(), 50, textAD.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());

        Text textADJ = new Text("adj");
        textADJ.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);
        textADJ.setFont(gc.getFont());
        gc.strokeRect(100, 0, textADJ.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(), textADJ.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
        gc.fillText(textADJ.getText(), 100, textADJ.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());

        canvas.snapshot(null, image);

        // Afficher l'image dans l'ImageView
        gridImageView.setImage(image);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(gridImageView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

And the ouput windows :

I don't find a way to get the distance between the top of my text and the baseline, how can I solve this issue (align the "adj" text to the top of the window) ?
Thanks,

Perhaps setting the text origin will help you position the text as you like.
